# Playwright redirected page is not loaded when running on local development enviroment

Tags: playwright

We are trying to use playwright for automation, when running the test against local development environment, the url redirects to a login page in which id not being loaded in the UI.

[image: redirected url page image]

We are using the Page.GotoAsync to navigate to the url. The issue seems to only happen on local development environment and not on development environments.

```
await Page.GotoAsync("http://localhost:4792/");
```

Please can someone advise how we can get the redirected page to load when running the test locally?

Comment: It seems like an app level issue. Does it happen when you try to open application manually?

Comment: No application loads correctly only happens when running playwright test

Comment: If it works in one environment and not in other , it suggests that it has something to do with the environment.

Comment: Anyways , playwright cannot cause application to not load.It has something to do with app. May be browser console errors might help.